# How to conditionally replace pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, replace

Say I have a dataframe as below, how to replace value, which is larger than 0.6, with 1, and replace value, with is less than 0.3, with 0, and replace all others with -1

```
        aaa       bbb       ccc
0  0.953893  0.977473  0.034157
1  0.693851  0.587930  0.584268
2  0.357185  0.429399  0.937016
3  0.384505  0.670054  0.657566
4  0.782799  0.479501  0.196721
5  0.548724  0.487478  0.277674
6  0.019224  0.426555  0.047267
7  0.746972  0.569147  0.973555
8  0.755425  0.885270  0.825515
9  0.427994  0.013501  0.982629
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
m1 = df.values > .6
m2 = df.values < .3
df = pd.DataFrame(np.select([m1,m2], [1,0], default=-1), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   aaa  bbb  ccc
0    1    1    0
1    1   -1   -1
2   -1   -1    1
3   -1    1    1
4    1   -1    0
5   -1   -1    0
6    0   -1    0
7    1   -1    1
8    1    1    1
9   -1    0    1
```

Another solution with double [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m1, 1, np.where(m2, 0, -1)), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   aaa  bbb  ccc
0    1    1    0
1    1   -1   -1
2   -1   -1    1
3   -1    1    1
4    1   -1    0
5   -1   -1    0
6    0   -1    0
7    1   -1    1
8    1    1    1
9   -1    0    1
```